# How to use the MvvmCross fluent API to bind a RecyclerView item's TextView to a property of its ViewModel on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross

I am using **MvvmCross** in my **Xamarin Android** project. I have an `MvxActivity` with an `MvxRecyclerView`, that I have assigned an item template in its layout file.

```
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_recycler_view" />
```

The ViewModel is quite simple, it consists just of one property that holds the data to display in the `RecyclerView`:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<ViewModelItem> _viewModelItems;
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelItem> ViewModelItems
    {
        get { return _viewModelItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _viewModelItems, value); }
    }    
}
```

Generally I like to use the MvvmCross fluent API as much as possible because of the implicit refactoring support.
So in my activity, I am binding a property of the `MvxRecyclerView` like this:

```
var recyclerView = View.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainView, MainViewModel>();
set.Bind(recyclerView)
    .For(v => v.ItemsSource)
    .To(vm => vm.ViewModelItems);
set.Apply();
```

So far so good. Now, the layout file for the item template basically just contains a `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/innerText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my `ViewModelItem` class looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

My question now is, how and where do I bind the `TextView.Text` property to the `ViewModelItem.Title` property using the fluent API?

I know it is quite easy to do without the fluent API by supplying an `MvxBind` attribute in the item template layout file, but I would really prefer a fluent API solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inherit from MvxRecyclerAdapter and create a custom Adapter for your RecyclerView. Override `OnCreateViewHolder` and return a custom ViewHolder.

```
public class MyAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
    public MyAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
        : base(bindingContext)
    {
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var itemBindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, this.BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);
        var view = this.InflateViewForHolder(parent, viewType, itemBindingContext);

        return new MyViewHolder(view, itemBindingContext);
    }
}
```

Within this ViewHolder you can use the Fluent API for binding.

```
public class MyViewHolder : MvxRecyclerViewHolder
{
    private readonly TextView textView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, IMvxAndroidBindingContext context)
        : base(itemView, context)
    {
        this.textView = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyViewHolder, ViewModelItem>();
            set.Bind(this.textView).To(x => x.Title);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }
}
```

In your Activity create the Adapter and add it to your RecyclerView:

```
var adapter = new MyAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)this.BindingContext);
recyclerView.Adapter = adapter;
```

and bind your Items to the ItemsSource of your Adapter:

```
set.Bind(this.adapter).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(x => x.ViewModelItems);
```

Comment: One thing to note, you may want to assign the click command over to your custom `ViewHolder` else any binding to ItemClick will have no affect. Example in [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938112/mvxrecyclerview-fluent-api-binding#answer-43055796).

Comment: This helps a lot, but I need to implement multiple viewtype, how can we implement that with customview holder ? I tried to find but everywhere shows with ItemTemplate Selector which use defaultViewHolder and binding from xml, I want to implement with above pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Ken's answer, I created a couple of support classes and extensions to generalize binding of items and pushed them together with a usage sample to github:

https://github.com/lauxjpn/MvxItemBinder

It allows you to write item bindings like the following:

```
var recyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.RecyclerView);

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainActivity, MainViewModel>();
set.Bind(recyclerView)
    .For(v => v.ItemsSource)
    .To(vm => vm.Items);
set.Apply();

recyclerView.BindItems<ItemViewModel>(this, (itemView, itemSet) =>
    itemSet.Bind(itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_template))
        .For(v => v.Text)
        .To(vm => vm.Title)
);
```

Or even shorter:

```
var recyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.RecyclerView);

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainActivity, MainViewModel>();
set.Bind(recyclerView.BindItems<ItemViewModel>(this, (itemView, itemSet) =>
        itemSet.Bind(itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_template))
            .For(v => v.Text)
            .To(vm => vm.Title)))
    .For(v => v.ItemsSource)
    .To(vm => vm.Items);
set.Apply();
```