# How to bind command to MvxRecyclerView using an adapter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have been searching for a solution to my problem and have tried multiple things, but my command is never successfully bound. You can see a few solutions in the code that I have tried, but they didn't work. I got a click event to work, but I really need to use the command on the ViewModel side of the application or I'll have to duplicate code. I have also tried to bind the `MvxRecyclerView` with `local:MvxBind="ItemClick NavigateMenuCommand"`, but that didn't work either.

Here is my command that I am trying to bind:

```
public ICommand NavigateMenuCommand {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => NavigateMenu()); }
    }

public void NavigateMenu()
    {
        // Just a placeholder to see if the command is working
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
```

Here is my main activity:

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);

        /* This didn't work
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
        set.Bind(FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.menuGrid)).For("ItemClick").To(vm => vm.NavigateMenuCommand);
        set.Apply(); */ 
    }

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        adapter = new Adapters.MenuItemRecylcerAdapter(this, Rpm.Data.Shared.User.AppList.ToArray());
        adapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
        view = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.menuGrid);
        view.SetAdapter(adapter);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        view.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        view.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;
    }
```

Here is my ViewHolder:

```
public class MenuItemAdapterViewHolder : MvxRecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView description { get; set; }
    public TextView icon { get; set; }


    public MenuItemAdapterViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener) : base(itemView)
    {
        description = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemDescription);
        icon = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemIcon);

        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.Position);
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
class MenuItemRecylcerAdapter : MvxRecyclerView.Adapter
{
    Activity _context;
    public Rpm.Models.Bases.Menu[] _menuItems;
    public EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

    public MenuItemRecylcerAdapter(Activity context, Rpm.Models.Bases.Menu[] menuItems)
    {
        _context = context;
        _menuItems = menuItems;
    }

    public override int ItemCount => _menuItems.Count();


    public override void OnBindViewHolder(MvxRecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {
        var item = _menuItems[position];
        var holder = viewHolder as MenuItemAdapterViewHolder;
        holder.description.Text = item.Description;
        holder.icon.SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        holder.icon.Text = item.IconFont;
    }

    public override MvxRecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var id = Resource.Layout.MenuItem;
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(id, parent, false);

        return new MenuItemAdapterViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
    }

    private void OnClick(int position)
    {
        ItemClick?.Invoke(this, position);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not assigning over the click commands in your adapter. See this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938112/mvxrecyclerview-fluent-api-binding/43055796#43055796).

Comment: I have tried your solution, but when setting the `itemBindingContext` I get an error on `this.BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder` that says "MenuItemRecyclerAdapter does not contain a definition for **BindingContext**" - Do you have the entire code for your adapter?

Comment: Your inheriting classes are different, are you using a custom a Adapters base clases (`MvxRecyclerView.Adapter` vs `MvxRecyclerAdapter`) and View Holder (`MvxRecyclerView.ViewHolder` vs `MvxRecyclerViewHolder`)? What version of MvvmCross are you using?

Comment: I am using MvvmCross 5.0.5. I am inheriting from classes that I saw on an example for implementing `MvxRecyclerView`.

Comment: If all you need to do is bind to an list of view model and have a command bound when selecting a row. Perhaps this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961865/how-to-use-the-mvvmcross-fluent-api-to-bind-a-recyclerview-items-textview-to-a#answer-39973732) to an example of using custom adapters and viewholder can help. Just remember to include the click assignment.